# Overriding the default click noise?

Tags: android, android-widget, audio, soundpool

By default, on my phone, clicking on apps, widgets, home button, etc makes a click noise. How do I override that click noise in a widget? I have a widget that plays a noise on click but right now it plays both my noise and the click noise. In the widget, I use soundpool to play the noise. This is the only code I use to access the noise.

```
 public class MakeState { ...
    SoundPool snd =new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    int soundID;

    ...
    public  void OnClick() {
    soundID = snd.load(getcontext(), R.raw.noise, 1);
    snd.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
  @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sound pool, int sampleid, int status) {
    soundPool.play(soundID, .6f, .6f, 1, 0, 1f);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the standard onClick noise using `setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ended up adding android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" to the layout xml.